# Allocate and initialize a vector of 20 elements in the range [20-200]. Calculate and print the average of elements divisible by 3

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm a beginner. Please help me.
This is my code:

```
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 32

.DATA
        VECTOR           DB 5 DUP(20H,20H,20H)           ;20 DE NR PE MAXIM 3 CIFRE
        KBD              DB 4,0,0,0,0,0
        TEN_POWER        DW 100,10,1
        NUMERE           DB 0Dh,0Ah,'Nr=$'
        MEDIE_ELEM_DIV3  DB 0
        NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3 DB 0
        SUMA             DW 0
        MSJ_SUMA         DB 'SUMA=$'
        FLAG             DB 0
        MSJ_CONTOR       DB 'NR_DIV3=$'
        NUMAR            DW 0
        NUMASC           DB 0Dh,0Ah,'Suma=     $'

.CODE
        START:         
                       MOV  AX, @DATA
                       MOV  DS, AX

                       CALL CITESTE
                       CALL CRLF
                       CALL AFISARE
                       CALL CRLF

                       CALL SUMA_NUMERE
                       CALL AFISARE_SUMA
                       CALL CRLF
                       CALL AFISARE_CONTOR


                       MOV  AH, 4CH
                       INT  21H

        CITESTE:       
                       MOV  CX, 5
                       MOV  DI,(OFFSET VECTOR)+3
        AGAIN:         PUSH CX
                       MOV  DX,OFFSET NUMERE
                       MOV  AH,9
                       INT  21H                            ; afiseaza sir de interogare

    
                       MOV  [KBD+1],0
                       MOV  AH,0Ah
                       MOV  DX,OFFSET KBD
                       INT  21H                            ; citeste numar cu 1 pana la 3 cifre
    
                       MOV  CL,[KBD+1]
                       MOV  CH,0
                       MOV  SI,(OFFSET KBD)+2
                       PUSH DI
                       SUB  DI,CX

        NEXT:          
                       MOV  AL,[SI]
                       MOV  [DI],AL
                       INC  SI                             ; memoreaza numar
                       INC  DI
                       LOOP NEXT
                       POP  DI
                       ADD  DI,3
                       POP  CX
                       LOOP AGAIN
                       RET
    
        AFISARE:       
                       MOV  CX, 5
                       MOV  SI,OFFSET VECTOR
        DISP:          
                       CALL CRLF
                       PUSH CX
                       MOV  CX,3

        NUM:           
                       MOV  AH,2
                       MOV  DL,[SI]
                       INT  21h                            ; afiseaza sirul de numere

                       INC  SI
                       LOOP NUM

                       POP  CX
                       LOOP DISP
                       RET
    
        CRLF:          
                       MOV  AH,2
                       MOV  DL,0Ah
                       INT  21h
                       MOV  AH,2
                       MOV  DL,0Dh
                       INT  21h
                       RET


       
        SUMA_NUMERE:   
                       MOV  CX, 5                          ;ITERARE CELE 20 ELEM VECTOR
                       MOV  SUMA, 0                        ; INITIALIZARE CU 0
                       MOV  [NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3], 0
                       MOV  BP, 0
        
        ASC_BIN:       
                       PUSH CX
                       MOV  CX, 3                          ;AM 3 CIFRE
                       MOV  BX, 10
                       MOV  SI, OFFSET VECTOR
                       
        AGAIN2:        MOV  AX,[NUMAR]
                       MUL  BX                             ; inmulteste suma partiala cu 10
                       MOV  DL,[SI]
                       MOV  DH,0
                       AND  DL,0FH                         ; conversie ASCII binar pentru cifra curenta
                       ADD  AX,DX                          ; aduna cifra curenta
                       MOV  [NUMAR],AX                     ;NUMAR E NR MEU IN BINAR

                       LOOP AGAIN2
                       POP  CX

                       CMP  BP, 35H
                       JE   END
                       INC  BP
        CONDITIE_DIV3: 
                       XOR  AX,AX

                       MOV  AX,[NUMAR]                     ;PUN IN AX NR IN BINAR
                       MOV  BL, 3
                       DIV  BL                             ;IMPART ELEMENTUL LA 3

                       CMP  AH, 0                          ;COMPAR RESTUL CU 0
                       JNE  NU_E_DIV3

                       ADD  [SUMA], AX                     ;ADAUGA IN SUMA NR DIV 3
                       ADD  [NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3], 1
                       INC  SI
                       

                      
        NU_E_DIV3:     
                       INC  SI
                       JMP  AGAIN2

        END:           RET


              
        AFISARE_SUMA:  
        BIN_ASC:       MOV  CX,4                           ; din numere binare pe 16 biti
        ; pot rezulta siruri ASCII cu 5 cifre
                       MOV  SI,OFFSET TEN_POWER            ; pointer spre tabela puterilor lui 10
                       MOV  DI,(OFFSET NUMASC)+7
        NEXT3:         
                       MOV  AX,[SUMA]
                       MOV  DX,0                           ; pregateste deimpartitul pe 32 de biti
                       DIV  WORD PTR [SI]                  ; obtine catul curent
                       MOV  [SUMA],DX                      ; salveaza restul curent
                       OR   AL,30H                         ; salveaza codul ASCII al cifrei curente
                       MOV  [DI],AL
                       INC  DI
                       ADD  SI,2                           ; avanseaza pointerul spre urmatoarea putere a lui 10
                       LOOP NEXT3
                       OR   DL,30H                         ; salveaza codul ASCII al ultimei cifre (cifra unitatilor)
                       MOV  [DI],DL

                       MOV  AH, 09h
                       MOV  DX, OFFSET NUMASC
                       INT  21H

                       RET

        AFISARE_CONTOR:
                       AND  [NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3], 0FH        ; masca ultimii 4 biti - obtinem cifra coresp caracterului
                       MOV  AH, 2                          ;pregatire pt afisarea caracterului
                       MOV  DL, 0DH                        ; carriage return
                       INT  21H                            ;apelarea intreruperii
                       MOV  AH, 2
                       MOV  DL, 0AH                        ;line feed
                       INT  21H
        

        REZULTAT:      
                       MOV  AH, 9                          ;pregatirea pentru afisarea unui string
                       MOV  DX, OFFSET MSJ_CONTOR          ;sirul FINAL 'NR_DIV3='
                       INT  21H

                       MOV  AL, [NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3]         ;NUMARUL
                       MOV  AH, 0                          ; deimpartitul este ax
                       MOV  BL, 10                         ;impartitorul
                       DIV  BL                             ;imparitm ax la bl -> al = catul si ah = restul
                       PUSH AX                             ;salvez pe stiva rez impartirii
                       CMP  AL, 0                          ;daca suma are o singrua cifra
                       JE   O_CIFRA                        ; sare si nu o mai afiseaza pe prima

                       MOV  DL, AL                         ; pt afisarea catului, adica a primei cifre din suma
                       OR   DL, 30H                        ;codul ascii al caracterului coresp cifrei din tabela ascii
                       MOV  AH, 2
                       INT  21H

        O_CIFRA:       
                       POP  AX                             ;scoate din stiva continutul reg ax
                       MOV  DL, AH                         ;pt afisarea restului, adica celei de a doua cifre
                       OR   DL, 30H                        ;obtinerea caract corespunzator
                       MOV  AH, 2                          ;pregatirea pt afisare
                       INT  21H                            ;apelarea intreruperii
                       RET
        

    END START
```

- I stored the numbers that I read from the stdin in ASCII and in the function where I want to make the sum.
- I iterate the array and convert each element in binary
- Then I tried to check the divisibility by dividing the number with 3.

But it doesn't work. It shows me the sum 0 and the contor of the numbers that are divisible with 3 to be 1.

I would appreciate any helpful input.

Comment: Your code is not 32-bit, but rather 16-bit. And probably your target platform is `emu8086`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### *NUMAR* is not correct

Each time that you want to calculate it, you need to reset its value to zero beforehand. And in the *AGAIN2* loop you forgot to increment SI so as to use all the different digits. Once this `inc si` is in place, you no longer need the other `INC SI` instructions that you have around the label *NU_E_DIV3:*.

```
    mov  NUMAR, 0    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    MOV  CX, 3        ; AM 3 CIFRE
    MOV  SI, OFFSET VECTOR
AGAIN2:
    MOV  AX, 10
    MUL  NUMAR        ; inmulteste suma partiala cu 10
    MOV  DL, [SI]
    AND  dx, 000Fh    ; conversie ASCII binar pentru cifra curenta
    ADD  AX, DX       ; aduna cifra curenta
    MOV  NUMAR, AX    ; NUMAR E NR MEU IN BINAR
    inc  si          <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    LOOP AGAIN2
```

### *SUMA* is 3x smaller

Because you add AX to *SUMA* directly after you divided AX by 3, what you add will not reflect the original value of *NUMAR*.

```
    MOV  AX, NUMAR   ; PUN IN AX NR IN BINAR
    MOV  BL, 3
    DIV  BL          ; IMPART ELEMENTUL LA 3
    CMP  AH, 0       ; COMPAR RESTUL CU 0
    JNE  AGAIN2      ; NU_E_DIV3
    mov  ax, NUMAR  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    ADD  [SUMA], AX
    inc  [NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3]
    JMP  AGAIN2
```

### *SUMA_NUMERE* does not loop good

You have `MOV CX,5` that you don't use later on, and you have `CMP BP, 35H` `JE END` that is much more than you have data items for!
You need to choose which you want to use...

### *AFISARE_SUMA* does too much

The *TEN_POWER* list has but 3 elements. You can't iterate 4 (+ 1) times (`; pot rezulta siruri ASCII cu 5 cifre`).