# convert an array of ascii numbers in binary numbers assembly x86 16-bit

Tags: assembly, x86-16, 16-bit

I want to convert all the ascii numbers that i stored in the array 'VECTOR' in binary form because i want to make the sum of them, but i don't know how to count how many digits that a number has to perform the convert.. can someone modify my function ASCBIN2??

```
DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 32


DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 32

.DATA
        VECTOR           DB 5 DUP(20H,20H,20H)            ;20 DE NR PE MAXIM 3 CIFRE
        KBD              DB 4,0,0,0,0,0
        TEN_POWER        DW 1000,100,10,1
        NUMERE           DB 0Dh,0Ah,'Nr=$'
        MEDIE_ELEM_DIV3  DB 0
        NR_ELEMENTE_DIV3 DB 0
        SUMA             DW 0
        MSJ_SUMA         DB 'SUMA=$'
        MSJ_CONTOR       DB 'NR_DIV3=$'
        NUMAR            DW 0                             ; numar in cod binar
        MESAJ_SUMA       DB 0Dh,0Ah,'Suma =     $'

.CODE
        START:  
                MOV  AX, @DATA
                MOV  DS, AX

                CALL CITESTE
                CALL CRLF
                CALL AFISARE
                CALL CRLF
                CALL ASCBIN

                MOV  AH, 4CH
                INT  21H

        CITESTE:
                MOV  CX, 5
                MOV  DI,(OFFSET VECTOR) + 3
        AGAIN:  PUSH CX
                MOV  DX,OFFSET NUMERE
                MOV  AH,9
                INT  21H                           ; afiseaza sir de interogare

                MOV  [KBD+1],0
                MOV  AH,0Ah
                MOV  DX,OFFSET KBD
                INT  21H                           ; citeste numar cu 1 pana la 3 cifre
    
                MOV  CL,[KBD+1]
                MOV  CH,0
                MOV  SI,(OFFSET KBD)+2
                PUSH DI
                SUB  DI,CX

        NEXT:   
                MOV  AL,[SI]
                MOV  [DI],AL
                INC  SI                            ; memoreaza numar
                INC  DI
                LOOP NEXT
                POP  DI
                ADD  DI,3
                POP  CX
                LOOP AGAIN
                RET
    
        AFISARE:
                MOV  CX, 5
                MOV  SI,OFFSET VECTOR
        DISP:   
                CALL CRLF
                PUSH CX
                MOV  CX,3

        NUM:    
                MOV  AH,2
                MOV  DL,[SI]
                INT  21h                           ; afiseaza sirul de numere IN ASCII

                INC  SI
                LOOP NUM

                POP  CX
                LOOP DISP
                RET
    
        CRLF:   
                MOV  AH,2
                MOV  DL,0Ah
                INT  21h
                MOV  AH,2
                MOV  DL,0Dh
                INT  21h
                RET

        ASCBIN: MOV  CX, 5

        ASCBIN2:
                PUSH CX
                MOV  CX, 2                        ; but if i have a number on 3 digits??
                MOV  BX, 10
                MOV  SI, OFFSET VECTOR

        AGAIN2: MOV  AX, [NUMAR]
                MUL  BX                            ; inmulteste suma partiala cu 10
                MOV  DL,[SI]
                MOV  DH,0
                AND  DL,0FH                        ; conversie ASCII binar pentru cifra curenta
                ADD  AX,DX                         ; aduna cifra curenta
                MOV  [NUMAR],AX
                INC  SI
                LOOP AGAIN2
                POP  CX

                RET

    END START
```

I need to iterate each element and convert it in binary. i dont know how to count the digits of every number

Comment: Any language can input text and convert to numeric.  Try the solution in C or a language you know.  Converting to assembly is very easy once you have a working algorithm in a working (C) program to refer to.  Then all you need to do is convert statement by statement and expression by expression, which is pretty easy to search/ask, i.e. how do I do this loop in assembly the same as I have in C?

Comment: New question, but what about the answer to your previous question? Status?

Comment: So in your example, you may have a number like `255` which is 3 digits, and you want to be able to tell if it's 3 digits versus something like `99` which is just 2?

Comment: If you don't know the number of digits ahead of time, use a loop that keeps going until you reach a non-digit.  e.g. [NASM Assembly convert input to integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19309749) shows how the compare+branching works for that, for base 10 input.  You've said you want base 2 output (or just a binary integer in a register?) but didn't specify what base the input string is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can someone modify my function ASCBIN2??

Your concern is about *ASCBIN2* only, and more precisely about `MOV CX, 2 ; but if i have a number on 3 digits??`.
Because of the definition `VECTOR DB 5 DUP(20H,20H,20H)` and the fact that you insert the numbers using right-alignment and space-padding on the left, you have to deal with next cases:

```
0-digit number eg. "   "
1-digit number eg. "  7"
2-digit number eg. " 94"
3-digit number eg. "208"
```

The solution must always process all 3 bytes, and **simply skip the byte if it contains a space character**:

```
ASCBIN2:
        PUSH CX
        mov  cx, 3               ; ALWAYS ALL THREE BYTES
        MOV  BX, 10
        MOV  SI, OFFSET VECTOR

AGAIN2:
        cmp  byte ptr [si], " "  ; SKIP LEADING SPACE(S)
        je   SkipSpace
        MOV  AX, [NUMAR]
        MUL  BX
        MOV  DL,[SI]             ; THIS IS "0" ... "9"
        MOV  DH,0
        AND  DL,0FH              ; CONVERT INTO 0 ... 9
        ADD  AX,DX
        MOV  [NUMAR],AX
SkipSpace:
        INC  SI
        LOOP AGAIN2
        POP  CX
```

Just like I wrote in the answer to another question of yours: [Allocate and initialize a vector of 20 elements in the range [20-200]. Calculate and print the average of elements divisible by 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76527222/allocate-and-initialize-a-vector-of-20-elements-in-the-range-20-200-calculate/76527726#76527726), you still need to **zero the *NUMAR* variable before doing this calculation**. Adding the zeroing and coming up with some improvements like combining 'Test For Space' with 'Conversion From ASCII':

```
ASCBIN2:
  push cx
  xor  bx, bx            ; So BH is zero
  mov  cx, 3             ; ALWAYS ALL THREE BYTES
  mov  si, OFFSET VECTOR
  xor  di, di            ; Let DI play the part of NUMAR
AGAIN2:
  mov  bl, [si]          ; BH=0 BL={" ", "0", "1", ... , "9"}
  sub  bl, "0"           ; From ["0","9"] to [0,9], BUT ...
  jb   SkipSpace         ; produces a borrow if BL was a space character
  mov  ax, 10            ; No need to waste a register on the CONST 10
  mul  di
  mov  di, ax
  add  di, bx
SkipSpace:
  inc  si
  dec  cx
  jnz  AGAIN2
  mov  NUMAR, di
  pop  cx
```

If allowable for the task at hand, replace the widening multiplication `mul di` by the non-widening multiplication `IMUL DI, 10` so that DX comes available as the counter:

```
ASCBIN2:
  mov   dx, 3             ; ALWAYS ALL THREE BYTES
  mov   si, OFFSET VECTOR
  xor   di, di            ; Let DI play the part of NUMAR
AGAIN2:
  movzx bx, byte ptr [si] ; BX={" ", "0", "1", ... , "9"}
  sub   bx, "0"           ; From ["0","9"] to [0,9], BUT ...
  jb    SkipSpace         ; produces a borrow if BX was a space character
  imul  di, 10
  add   di, bx
SkipSpace:
  inc   si
  dec   dx
  jnz   AGAIN2
  mov   NUMAR, di
```